# Definition of an indexed sequences of Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm reading a book on probability theory and in one section the author is using a sequence of random variables

$$X_{N_k}$$

where $(X)_n)$ is a sequence of random variables and $(N_k)_k$ are random variables taking values in the positive integers. How is $X_{N_k}$ defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{T},\mathbb{P})$, a random variable $X$ is a function :
$$\begin{align*}
  X \colon \Omega &\to E\\
  \omega &\mapsto X(\omega).
\end{align*}, $$
with $E$ a set.

Here, $X_{N_k}$ is a function defined by :
$$\begin{align*}
  X_{N_k} \colon \Omega &\to E\\
  \omega &\mapsto X_{N_k(\omega)}(\omega).
\end{align*} $$

Answer (score 1):

$X_{N_k}$ is the value of the term in the sequence $(X_n)_{n\in\Bbb N^+}$ whose index is the value of the term in the sequence $(N_m)_{m\in\Bbb N^+}$ whose index is the value of $k$.

$$(X_n)_{n\in\Bbb N^+}=(X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots)\\[2ex](N_m)_{m\in\Bbb N^+}=(N_1,N_2,N_3,\ldots)$$

So if $k=2$, $N_2=3$, and $X_3=1$ then $X_{N_k}=1$